# How to implement vue-pdf with Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, pdf, npm, vuex

I have a Vuex state where i define a selected pdf:

```
  selectedPDF: "/svg/example.pdf"
```

(hardcoded for testing purposes)

Vuex getter:

```
getSelectedPDF: state => { return state.selectedPDF; }
```

And here's basic component structure:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pdf :src="selectedPDF"></pdf>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import pdf from "vue-pdf";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "ExamplePdf",
  data: () => {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      selectedPDF: "selectedPDF"
    })
  },
  components: {
    pdf
  }
};
```

My idea is load pdfs in the Vuex state dynamically, and then use the example component above to display said pdf in multiple places. However, once i use the component somewhere (where it displays the pdf properly), if i try to use it somewhere else, it just displays blank page.
Is it actually possible to do this with this npm module?

Comment: Can you please share your Vuex code, "getters selectedPDF"

Comment: @chans Here you go sir, sorry for the late reply: `getSelectedPDF: state => {
    return state.selectedPDF;
  }`
This is the Vuex getter that takes the `selectedPDF` from the state.

Comment: You are doing it in a right way. Did you see any errors in console, If so, please post that too

Comment: @chans No, the console does not output any errors. However, i've noticed that the fetch request that gets the pdf only occurs in the first instance of the component, and when i try to re-use the same component elsewhere, it does not fetch the pdf again. Not that i think it should, however since the pdf is not displayed, it might solve the issue...